I keep getting error anytime I try deploying a Nuxt-app from my github repo to vercel
[error] [nitro] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received function
"this is the error I saw on vercel when I checked why it didn't deploy".
I tried creating the app from start to be sure I didn't punch a wrong line of code @ some point and hoped that the error would not persist but apparently, it is still the same.

Quite a lot of similar issues online, give it a search.
